# jQuery Div attr (width = $('#immagineCont').attr('clientWidth'); = undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, undefined, attr

im no expert javascript coder.
i used like 5 hours now trying alot of different stuff. and i noticed some things that i cant figure out
im trying to get this to work

```
width = $('#immagineCont').attr('clientWidth');
```

but it returns undefined
i tried doing

```
width = $('#immagineCont').attr('id');
```

witch returned #immagineCont i guess is correct.

when i use

```
 $('#immagineCont')
```

i get this in firebug 1)
http://bildr.no/view/1325119 2)
http://bildr.no/view/1325120

so what im trying to do is get the damn clientWidth witch seems impossible. i even tryed children("0") and children("#0")
im going blow my brains soon ^^

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`attr` would only work if there was an attribute with this name.

You may simply use

```
width = $('#immagineCont').get(0).clientWidth;
```

but you more probably need

```
width = $('#immagineCont').width();
```

which is more reliable when you want to do something that works the same across browsers (but doesn't include padding and borders).

You might also be interested by [outerWidth](http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/).

A note about what happens and the need for `get(0)` : a jQuery collection (like `$('#immagineCont')`) wraps one or more standard DOM objects that you can get using `get(i)` or `[i]`. If you want to access native properties of the DOM object, when jQuery doesn't offer a proxy function, you need to get this native object first.

Comment: +1 possibly `outerWidth()` as well if you want to include padding and borders

Comment: wow that seemed to work. so i need to use get(number). i googled like mad and it sayd that no where :).

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks. Added the link to outerWidth.

Comment: @coldasice `get(0)` gives you the native DOM object.

Comment: im still a bit rusty on this js and doom stuff^^.. but any ways just that 1 thing solved alot of my questions. now i got it working :=). so far just some more :)

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery `width()` for this purpose:

```
var width = $('#immagineCont').width();
```

Also there is no attribute set to the element called clientWidth. This is a javascript property so it can be retrieved by dereferencing the jQuery object:

```
var width = $('#immagineCont')[0].clientWidth;
```

Comment: liked more the get version. thanks. all these so fast. and google hated me :()